# show more/show less for multiple lists not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, list, html-lists

I have been trying to create lists with show more and show less buttons. My code is working for single 'ul' list. But when I create multiple list, list items are not showing. Only button appears.

Can u please tell me how to write script for multiple 'ul' lists with show more/show less buttons.

Also I have to use same id and class for all lists and buttons

Thanks in advance..

```
    //html
        <div class="wrapper">
        <ul class="list">
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item2</li>
        <li>item3</li>
        <li>item4</li>
        <li>item5</li>
        <li>item6</li>
        <li>item7</li>
        </ul> 
        <button id="next">+ Show More</button>
        <button id="less">- Show Less</button>
    </div>
        
        <div class="wrapper">
        <ul class="list">
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item2</li>
        <li>item3</li>
        <li>item4</li>
        <li>item5</li>
        <li>item6</li>
        <li>item7</li>
        </ul> 
        <button id="next">+ Show More</button>
        <button id="less">- Show Less</button>
    </div>
        
        <div class="wrapper">
        <ul class="list">
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item2</li>
        <li>item3</li>
        <li>item4</li>
        <li>item5</li>
        <li>item6</li>
        <li>item7</li>
        </ul> 
        <button id="next">+ Show More</button>
        <button id="less">- Show Less</button>
    </div>

//more list...
        
        //Script
        
        $(document).ready(function(){
        
              var list = $(".list li");
              var numToShow = 3;
              var button = $("#next");
              var link = $('#less');
              var numInList = list.length;
              list.hide();
              if (numInList > numToShow) {
                button.show();
                link.hide();
              }
              list.slice(0, numToShow).show();
        
              button.click(function(){
                  var showing = list.filter(':visible').length;
                  list.slice(showing - 1, showing + numToShow).fadeIn();
                  var nowShowing = list.filter(':visible').length;
                  if (nowShowing >= numInList) {
                    button.hide();
                    link.show();
        
                  }
              });
              link.click(function () {
                $('.list li').not(':lt(3)').hide();
                button.show();
                link.hide();
            });
        
        });
        
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you want to have more than a single list, you can't set the same ID to all of them, since they're in the same document, and the ID for an element must be unique across all the document.

Comment: But key point of making it work dynamically with multiple lists is wrapping each list in a wrapper and then retrieving the list you want to show more data for using the .next(), .closest(), .parent() and such methods.

Comment: Do you know which `<li>` to be hidden initially? If yes I'd just add a class to them and toggle class. Are you trying to display as much as possible with available space?

Comment: I am taking the list dynamically from the database..I cant add toggle class to the list

Answer (score 0):

Updated your code to use classes, siblings(), children() & next()

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        
        var numToShow = 3;
        $(".list li").hide();
        $('.wrapper ul').each(function(){
           var list = $(this).children("li");
           var button = $(this).siblings(".next");
           var less = $(this).siblings('.less');
           var numInList = list.length;
           if (numInList > numToShow) {
              button.show();
              less.hide();
           }
          //$(this).children("li:lt('+ numToShow +')").show();
          list.slice(0, numToShow).show();
        });
        
        $('button.next').click(function(){
          var list = $(this).siblings(".list").children("li");
          var numInList = list.length;
          var showing = list.filter(':visible').length;
          list.slice(showing - 1, showing + numToShow).fadeIn();
          var nowShowing = list.filter(':visible').length;
          if (nowShowing >= numInList) {
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).next('button.less').show();
          }
        });

        $('button.less').click(function () {
          $(this).siblings(".list").children("li").not(':lt(3)').hide();
          $(this).siblings('button.next').show();
          $(this).hide();
        });
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="list">
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item2</li>
      <li>item3</li>
      <li>item4</li>
      <li>item5</li>
      <li>item6</li>
      <li>item7</li>
    </ul>
    <button id="next" class="next">+ Show More</button>
    <button id="less" class="less">- Show Less</button>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="list">
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item2</li>
      <li>item3</li>
      <li>item4</li>
      <li>item5</li>
      <li>item6</li>
      <li>item7</li>
    </ul>
    <button id="next" class="next">+ Show More</button>
    <button id="less" class="less">- Show Less</button>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="list">
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item2</li>
      <li>item3</li>
      <li>item4</li>
      <li>item5</li>
      <li>item6</li>
      <li>item7</li>
    </ul>
    <button id="next" class="next">+ Show More</button>
    <button id="less" class="less">- Show Less</button>
  </div>
```